# Is MVC a design pattern only or Programming Technology

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, model-view-controller

Is MVC a design pattern only or Programming Technology? If I violation the MVC pattern like ASP.Net Form Application then any performance issue arise or not.?

Answer (score 4):

MVC is neither a design pattern or a technology.  It's a software architecture pattern.  See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

The difference between a design pattern and a software architecture pattern is that design patterns tend to be simpler and apply to specific components of an application, while architecture patterns are broader and apply to the application as a whole.

In any event, there is also various pieces of technology called MVC, which are based on the MVC pattern.  For instance, ASP.NET MVC is the official name for the flavor of MVC created by Microsoft for use in web applications.  This is a specific implementation of MVC.

Violation of the MVC pattern has nothing to do with performance, and is largely an issue dealing with maintainability.  The MVC pattern stresses separation of concerns to make designing and maintaining your application easier, and making your application less fragile to change.

Answer (score 2):

MVC is just a architecture pattern not a technology, and its goal is separating concerns, you should know something that you can use MVC pattern and Webforms together, and if MVC does not separate Model View and Controller then you are doing something else not MVC

Comment: simply >You are wrong! i think you need to read the answer carefully! by the way your example is wrong too! it's like calling the internet IE!